# Minimum screen size for LaTeX

Tags: performance

I'm getting a new laptop soon (supposedly, anyway; I've been saying that for months).  My current laptop is fairly light for its size, but I'd prefer something much lighter.  The only way to do that is to settle for a smaller screen, but I'm worried that a small screen will be inconvenient for LaTeX work.  In the vertical direction, it's nice to have a whole page of text fit on the screen without scrolling.  If you accept Latex's generous default margins, this is doable on a medium sized screen, but maybe not on a small one unless you zoom out and make the text tiny.  In the horizontal direction: is it practical to have an editor and previewer side by side with a small screen?

I guess I've babbled for a while without actually asking a question.  So here it is: what's the smallest practical laptop screen size for LaTeX?  (This will be my primary machine, no external monitors or anything like that.)

Comment: A display capable of showing one line of text, max. 80 characters. For the resulting PDF, however, something slightly bigger could prove useful.

Comment: My laptop has a 13" screen, and I'm glad it's not any smaller when I'm doing LaTeX work. On the other hand, I don't think I'd be better off, LaTeX-wise, if I had a laptop with a 15" screen. I have a colleague who has a MacBook Air with an 11" screen, which he uses for all of his LaTeX-related work. He says he does fine, but he's also a few years younger than me and not as dependent on reading glasses as I am to read what's on a screen. So: how's your visual acuity, and do you need reading glasses (or may you need them soon)?

Comment: Isn't that question too broad or opinion based? I've seen peopple using a size of 7 pt in their editor. Was hard to read for me even with glasses. Using preview or not is also a matter of taste.

Comment: Depends on your definition of practical, I'd say.

Comment: Mico: I can see nearby things, but not faraway things.  But my definition of "far" so gotten so bad that I need to lean in to see what's on my screen, or else put on my glasses.  So, you claim 13" is fine, with a side-by-side preview?  I like 12pt fonts on both the editor and pdf.  I was going to get a 15.6" screen, out of fear that anything much smaller wouldn't work well.

Comment: Mico: if you'd posted your comment as an answer, I'd probably have accepted it; you were the only to give me concrete numbers.  Since you didn't I figure you reputation score is high enough to not be too offended if I accept the only official answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, on a lightweight-small laptop, it's practical for folks to use LaTeX with preview.  What you can do with a small screen is have about 60 character wide code, then on the overview side, shrink the preview to thumbnail size pages, then you can see the general layout of the page even though you can't read the specific text.  So, on the code side you see the precise text and code, and on the preview side you see where it's going to fall, though not legible text.

Now if you're planning on running LaTeX on smart-watch screen-size, or 7" tablet, then that's definitely NOT practical. It's TOO small.

(That's in my opinion, since it's a general question it receives a general answer)

Comment: I don't think I want to resort to making the pdf so small I can't read it.  At what point do you figure that would happen?  Do you think 13" is doable with readable pdfs?  Thanks so much.

Comment: If you really want to look at all the fine pdf detail with a 13" screen, I think you'd want to do the equivalent of a pdf Quick Build (which can be as fast as pressing Alt-1 in Kile) at that point a pdf is generated, and you can toggle back and forth between your code, and the pdf whenever you like.  I assume you're generating default letter-size pages with default size fonts.  That's what I do rather than having a live pdf image, which I find distracting when I'm trying to write and code.  If previewing live, you'd have to test it yourself.

Comment: I'd love to have a live pdf image, but I didn't know it was practical.  A typical LaTeX build takes at least a second, even for a tiny file, because it has to load the article class and stuff.  That's too slow for anyone who's typing speed is not measured in minutes per word, instead of words per minute.  And what happens if the file doesn't build cleanly?  Does the pdf blink out of existence every time you type an extra slash?  I think I vaguely remember seeing a website that does something like this, but never a desktop app.

Comment: While your typing, you should be focusing on Content, not Format.  Only occasionally should you even be interested in Format.  It's not practical to be looking at the pdf every second while your typing.  The whole idea behind LaTeX is to take Format out of your mind, knowing that it will be handled properly.  That's unlike word processors where the user is constantly concerned with the format, as they type.

Comment: That's fine if my goal is to write 3 brand new paragraphs.  Less so if I'm making edits.  Or if I'm trying to learn a new feature.  Also, sometimes formatting is really important.  Try making a slideshow (I use beamer) without worrying about formatting, because "it will be handled properly".  I could go on and on: try to change a document into LNCS format without having a preview handy.  Even worse: try changing your document from single column to two columns per page.  Also: I can't read complex math in LaTeX: I need to look at the pdf to read what I just wrote one minute ago.

Comment: I personally think you need a laptop (or desktop) with a larger screen size to do the type of work you want.  Tiny consumer devices are cool gadgets to own and showoff, but the screen is an important aspect of productivity, if that's your goal.

Comment: Yep, that's eventually what I decided too.  I'm typing this on my shiny new 15.6" laptop.